# Visualize mjpeg-over-http streams in browser with html5

Tags: html, canvas, mobile-safari, jpeg, mjpeg

Alright, I have a server that serves a [motion-jpeg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_Jpeg#M-JPEG_over_HTTP) stream over http. What I would like to be able to do is connect to the server and visualize the stream in a browser, preferibly inside a `canvas` element. Browser should be Safari Mobile.

Is it possible to take the stream with XMLHttpRequest, take the single JPEG images out and put them within a `canvas` element? Keep in mind that the stream is live, thus possibly endless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOs mobile Safari supports MJPEG natively over http.  Is there specific reason you need it in Canvas? 
see http://bridgecam2.halton.gov.uk/mjpg/video.mjpg?camera=1 on a ipad/iphone

Comment: This example is not working any more at least not on iOS6.1.3

Answer (score 12):

Sorry to revive an old topic but i was faced with this problem and i didnt want to use an other player just native html5

I found one way to display the video inside html5 with "poster" attribute

```
<video width="360" height="420" controls poster="/video" autoplay>
        <source src="/audio.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
</video>
```

Might not be what you expected but it works.

Comment: This answer needs some serious upvotes. Solved my problem after hours of searching. I am showing an mjpg stream from a trendnet ipcam. The response headers tell me my content-type is multipart/x-mixed-replace. This works like a charm